# How to Listen data changes at NodeJs websocket

Tags: node.js, websocket

In my module, there are a Client<->Server1<->Server2

Client request a websocket to Server1
Server2 pass a message to Server1

I have no idea how to listen on Server1 when Server1's message changed
Please suggest me some method.

```
var temp ;
var aSocket ;
app.post( '/synReciver', function( req, res ) {
     console.log( 'I'm Server2, and I get Message from Server2' ) ;
     temp = req.headers ;
     res.end();
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socketIO) {
     socketIO.on('fromWebClient', function (webClientData) {
         aSocket[socketIO.id] = socketIO;
     });

     var interval= setInterval(function() {
       if ( temp[0] != null ) {
          aSocket[socketIO.id].emit('A message from server2 ' +temp[0] ) ;
       }
     },1000);

     socketIO.on('disconnect', function () {
         console.log('DISCONNECTED FROM CLIENT');
     });
 });
```

I hope the socket don't emit when connection, but wait for the temp array changed

Comment: Server2 will call /synReciver to change the temp array

Answer (score 0):

It's work

```
 var interval= setInterval(function() {
   aSocket[socketIO.id] = socketIO;

   if ( typeof(temp) != 'undefined' && temp != null ) {

      aSocket[socketIO.id].emit('pushToWebClient', temp);
      temp = {} ;
   } else {
         console.log('temp are null');
   }
```